# Mongoose - Return Only Updated Item using findOneAndUpdate and Array Filters

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like so:

```
documents [
  _id
  items [
    name
    type
    subitems [
      _id
      name
    ]
  ]
]
```

I want to update a a subitem using a combination of `document.id`, `item.name`, `item.type`, and `subitem.id`. I have a working findOneAndUpdate query using Mongoose.

```
  db.models.Document.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(document.id), 'items.name': item.name, 'items.type': item.type },
    { $set: { 'items.$.subitems.$[subitem].name': 'New Name' } },
    {
      fields: { _id: 0, 'items.$.subitems': 1 },
      arrayFilters: [
        { 'subitems._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(subitem.id) }
      ]
    },
    (err, section) => {
      console.log(section);
    }
  );
```

In turn, this query returns:

```
{ items: [ subitems: [{ _id: 'IDHERE', name: 'NAME' }, { _id: 'IDHERE2', name: 'NAME2' }], name: 'Name', type: 'Type' } ] }
```

However, I only want the exact subitem that the query updates using the array filter.

```
{ _id: 'IDHERE', name: 'NAME' }
```

Can I do this in one go using Mongo or do I have to filter the results after fetching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will have to filter it after because mongoose doesn't support that kind of functionality in the findOneAndUpdate method...
It returns the full object after doing an update.

Answer (score 2):

To display only the required fields, `projection` can be used. Since, you are trying to get only selected fields within an array, `filter` is the only available option present in the MongoDB right now.